# Vbscript how to find the first char from the end in text

Tags: vbscript

I have problem with find the first char from the end in text.
For example, find space(" ") or new line(vbCrLf) on  "Father go home" i get the index of first space from the end and on "Father go home/ntomorrow" i get the index of /n.

my code:

```
Function checkTextFunction( i_valueCheck)
    Dim whereSpace
    Dim WhereNewLine
    Dim indexOFirstSpaceFromTheEnd
    If Right(i_valueCheck,1) = " " Or Right(i_valueCheck,1) = vbCrLf Then
        indexOFirstSpaceFromTheEnd = -1
    Else
        whereSpace = InStrRev(i_valueCheck, " ", -1,0)
        WhereNewLine = InStrRev(i_valueCheck, vbCrLf, -1,0)
        If whereSpace < WhereNewLine Then 
            indexOFirstSpaceFromTheEnd = whereSpace
        Else
            indexOFirstSpaceFromTheEnd = WhereNewLine
        End If
    End IF
    WriteLogFileLine "indexOFirstSpaceFromTheEnd: " & indexOFirstSpaceFromTheEnd & " Right(i_valueCheck,1): " & Right(i_valueCheck,1) & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    checkTextFunction = indexOFirstSpaceFromTheEnd
End Function
```

but i don't find the first occurrence with the lines

```
    whereSpace = InStrRev(i_valueCheck, " ", 1)
    WhereNewLine = InStrRev(i_valueCheck, vbCrLf,1)
```

i get always 0.

Someone have idea?

******* I edit  my question !!!!.

Thanks,

Tal

Comment: Pls provide some test string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final answer: if the last char in "i_valueCheck" is not space or vbCrLf it's find the first case(space or vbCrLf) from the end of "i_valueCheck".

```
    Function checkTextFunction( i_valueCheck)
        Dim whereSpace
        Dim whereNewLine
        Dim indexOFirstSpaceFromTheEnd
        If Right(i_valueCheck,1) = " " Or Right(i_valueCheck,2) = vbCrLf Then
            indexOFirstSpaceFromTheEnd = -1
        Else
            whereSpace = InStrRev(i_valueCheck, " ", -1, 0)
            whereNewLine = InStrRev(i_valueCheck, vbCrLf, -1, 0)

            If whereSpace > 0 And (whereSpace > whereNewLine Or whereNewLine = 0) Then 
                indexOFirstSpaceFromTheEnd = whereSpace
            ElseIf whereNewLine > 0 And (whereNewLine > whereSpace Or whereSpace = 0) Then
                indexOFirstSpaceFromTheEnd = whereNewLine       
            Else                                   
                indexOFirstSpaceFromTheEnd = -1
            End If
        End If                                              
        checkTextFunction = indexOFirstSpaceFromTheEnd End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

1. vbCrLf is actually 2 characters, so you want to specify `Right(i_valueCheck, 2) = vbCrLf`
2. If the character is not in the string, then `InStrRev` will return 0.. which would mean it is always the first occurrence.  The second `If` statement should be a little more explicit in terms of the values of the variables.
3. Since you're not initializing `indexOFirstSpaceFromTheEnd`... If there are no vbCrLf or " " characters- it will remain empty.  Therefore you should add a check in order to return a value every time...  regardless of the string.  I picked one million arbitrarily.

```vbs
Function checkTextFunction(ByRef i_valueCheck)
    Dim whereSpace
    Dim whereNewLine
    Dim indexOFirstSpaceFromTheEnd

    If Right(i_valueCheck,1) = " " Or Right(i_valueCheck,2) = vbCrLf Then
        indexOFirstSpaceFromTheEnd = -1
    Else
        whereSpace = InStrRev(i_valueCheck, " ", -1, 0)
        whereNewLine = InStrRev(i_valueCheck, vbCrLf, -1, 0)

        If whereSpace > 0 And (whereSpace < whereNewLine Or whereNewLine = 0) Then 
            indexOFirstSpaceFromTheEnd = whereSpace
        ElseIf whereNewLine > 0 And (whereNewLine < whereSpace Or whereSpace = 0) Then
            indexOFirstSpaceFromTheEnd = whereNewLine
        End If
    End If

    If indexOFirstSpaceFromTheEnd = vbEmpty Then indexOFirstSpaceFromTheEnd = 1000000

    WriteLogFileLine "indexOFirstSpaceFromTheEnd: " & _ 
                      indexOFirstSpaceFromTheEnd    & _
                      " Right(i_valueCheck,1): "    & _ 
                        Right(i_valueCheck,1)       & vbCrLf & vbCrLf

    checkTextFunction = indexOFirstSpaceFromTheEnd
End Function
```

This should help you get started...  realistically- if you want to find the first occurrence of vbCrLf or " " then you're going to have to operate a `While` loop in order to keep checking (with `InStrRev`) that the index is **actually** the last occurrence.

For example:  with the code above... look at the output of `checkTextFunction(Space(2) & "test")`

Comment: I got confused, I wanted the first case from the end.

why you write -1 in function " InStrRev(i_valueCheck, vbCrLf, -1, 0)"?

Comment: It's the parameter for specifying the start index of the reverse search. -1 is default for the last index.

Comment: You're going to have to be a little more specific than that.